# Missing accounts in merchant center page

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-pay

I want to add a boarding pass to google pay. I followed this page '[Get Access to rest API](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/basic-setup/get-access-to-rest-api)'.
In one of the steps, we should go to [Merchant center](https://pay.google.com/gp/m/issuer/list) and select my account, but for me, in the merchant center page there isn't any account and my page is empty.

What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: It says: "Your Google Pay API for Passes account should have been created for you by your Google point of contact." Are you able to follow up with your Google point of contact?

Comment: @Soc thanks, I had to wait and after some hours everything is fine.

Comment: So it took some time for the changes to become active?

Comment: @Soc yes, it took some time